# ¿Como iniciar un proyecto de github por medio de npm en nodejs?

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, npm

He deseado instalar todas las dependencias en nodejs por medio de los siguientes comando y no me funciona el proyecto, he tratado con otros repo similares y me sigue dando el mismo problema.

```
git clone urlrepo
```

**Hasta aquí ningun problema**
npm install -D

Pero ejecuto este comando

```
npm run dev
```

no me muestra lo que esta en el proyecto, es decir, renderiza pero en blanco. Hago uso de reactjs.

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar a solucionar este problema.

No estoy usando express, dado que estoy iniciando.

```
PS E:\frontend api connection\semillero-react> npm i -D
npm WARN frontend@1.0.0 No description

npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND 
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.org/source-map failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.org
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\juanr\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-14T15_59_10_121Z-debug.log´´´
```

Comment: ¿Has mirado las consolas para ver si hay algún error?

Comment: Hola pablo, mira que me sale lo siguiente al realizar npm install -D y he eliminado el proyecto y del mismo modo desinstale nodejs y nada de eso me ha funcionado. Ya actualizo lo que me muestra en consola.

Comment: `request to https://registry.org/source-map failed` Ese dominio no existe. Es posible que en tu empresa tengan un repositorio local de npm?

Comment: Pues ejecute otro comando y logre solucionar un pequeño inconveniente que tenia, segun lei era que no tenia acceso a la red y por medio del uso de ping 8.8.8.8 y del mismo modo a google.com, hice lo mismo ```ping registry.npmjs.org``` y ya me funciono, muchas gracias por tu colaboración.